# Insert streaming data into hive

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hadoop-streaming

My scenerio is
In my project we get 200 msg from kafka every mins and needs to store in hive table using avro format.

If we use insert scriptf or each message, i believe it takes long time to insert for each message.
Is there is any idea, for this streaming data which way we have to use to insert into hive with good perforance.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in using Apache storm as a streaming mechanism.This can be accomplished using kafka-to-hive bolt using storm which you can easily search for. Please let me know if you are then I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Our flow is something like below. Complete implementing in spark with java.                                                                         kafka listner  ---> spark engine(preprocessing of message) ---> some validation over received message ---> push to hive table .

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create an external table and send the msgs to the external table location.

Comment: Creating a file for each message means 200*60*24=288000  files a day. Which results a overhead for namenode(metadata).

Comment: how the insert into statement gets created in runtime?

like 
insert into table values(1)(2)(3);

 or

insert into table values(1);
insert into table values(2);
insert into table values(3);

Comment: i suggest another way in your flow:

1)kafka listner --->2) spark engine(preprocessing of message) ---> 3)some validation over received message ---> 4)push to hive table

how is the validation done in the 3rd step?

if it is done in spark why dont u use saveAsTextFile to the external table's location.